# How to dynamically select multiple items in ion-select popup

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I have a requirement for selecting multiple options in the ion-select popup dynamically. Is it possible to do so?
Here is my code:

```
<div class="filter-item">
      <p>field name</p>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label></ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="filter.ids" multiple="true">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{item.Id}}" selected="{{item.selected}}">{{item.Status}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
    </div>
```

Could anyone please help me out with this feature. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is pre-selected options right?

Comment: Try using square brackets with [selected] and [value]. Don't forget remove the curly braces from them.

Comment: This is not working for me the even if I changed the selected and value to square brackets and removed the curly braces for the data assigned to it. Could you please let me know if there is any other solution.

Comment: ngModel (filter.ids) should match the values (item.Id) and by default the will be mark as selected

Comment: is this solved?